# Trying to include PHP code in Jquery droppable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm building a Form builder CMS and I'm trying to access information from my database on to the dropped elements.

The problem being;
The index file is PHP and draggable/droppable element is fetched from another javascript file as a variable. In the JS file I tried adding this to the variable where I want the code to be executed:

```
txtboxEdit += "<? include 'db.php' ?>";
```

But this is the output when my element is dropped:

```
<!--? include 'db.php' ?-->
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this or maybe there's a better way (probably is, haha). Is there something that could "force" the code to be outputted as text?

Thx

Comment: JavaScript files are not PHP processed.

Comment: I know, that's why I want it to be added as the text it is, that way the php file might be able to process it?

Comment: Just put it into HTML and grab it with JavaScript from there.

Comment: The PHP is processed on the serverside. Anything you do with you JS is happening on the clientside (after the rendered PHP is already delivered).
You could implement a REST-API on the serverside and fetch the data as and when needed with AJAX-requests.